# DataFrame Formatted Output

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, xlsxwriter

So I'm a newbie here at the stack and on python. My sample dataframe and expected output are mentioned below. Please help.

I have a data frame which writing to excel using `xlsxwriter` engine.
[Sample dataframe snapshot is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzNPt.png)

**Target:** I want to search each row having the total at first column and apply formatting as shown in the below screenshot until the end of the column.
[Expected output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6moKB.png)

Tried to find the way of reading all the rows having total in data frame using

```
Total = final_df[final_df['Placement# Name'] == 'Total']
```

but now can't figure out, how to format them, main point is to format color.

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @Isma I understand the concern here. However i simply want a logic to format the rows which i'm writing to excel using pandas and xlsxwriter.the data frame I'm producing is through bunch of code and directly writing to excel. the only I want to format these rows with colors. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general to fill a cell you can use this:

```
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_bg_color('green')
```

And adding the parameter `cell_format=format` in

```
worksheet.write()
```

You can find more info [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html)